# unsuccessful data transmission between client and server in java socket connection

Tags: java, sockets

i have written a simple client server program in java using sockets. when i run the ServerClas.java on one machine and Clientclas.java on another, looks like the sockets are connected but data is not being transmitted. I can tell that they are connected because when the Server.java is terminated in the server machine, an exception is caught at client saying that the connection was reset. I am unable to figure why the data is not being transmitted.
Please correct my mistakes.

Machines are connected using netgear router.
java runtime environment is javase1.6

Clientclas.java is

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
    name=s.nextLine();
    try {
        InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.9");
        Socket sock = new Socket(add,7777);
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        out.write("Hai ..!! This is "+name+". Im connected to you");

        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        int i;
        while((i=is.read())!=-1)
        {
            System.out.write(i);
        }
        sock.close();
        s.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Cannot connect to host");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ServerClas.java is

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
    name = s.nextLine();
    ServerSocket sock;
    try{
        System.out.println("terminating...");
    sock = new ServerSocket(7777);
    System.out.println("Your prog is listening to clients on port 7777 on"+sock.getInetAddress());
    Socket soc = sock.accept();

    InputStream is = soc.getInputStream();
    is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    int i;
    while((i=is.read())!=-1)
    {
        System.out.write(i);
    }
    System.out.println("Data recieved");

    OutputStream os = soc.getOutputStream();
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    out.write("Hai ..!! This is "+ServerClas.name+". Im connected to you");
    out.flush();        }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Excption caught");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    s.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read data from the input stream, you read until it is close, but you don't close the connection until after you have recieved a reply, which you won't get until you close the connection.

i.e. you have a deadlock.

You need some way of knowing when the message has been sent, while the connection is still open so you can send a reply.  I suggest sending a `\n` at the end of your line and stop reading when you see this.

Comment: I couldn't understand you clearly. can you please elaborate the first two lines of your suggestion

Comment: @jagadeesh `sock.close();` (as would `out.close()`) in the client will cause `(i=is.read())!=-1` in the server to happen. It does not so A waits for B to do something before it will continue and at the same time B waits for A to do something. That's called a deadlock because noone can continue.

Comment: @zapl          
i got it. client to server is okay now.i should repeat the same on server side too after data is written to the output stream from server. correct?? but socket exception is being caught at client saying that "socket is closed" in that case.

Comment: is.read() doesn't read a -1 until you close() the connection, but you don't do this until you have read the reply, which you are not sending until you close the connection. You have a catch-22 situation.

Comment: @jagadeesh Which is why is suggested you not close the connection but send some way the other end knows it has read the whole message, e.g. `\n`  You can't send a reply after the connection has been closed.